# calculate or find a lower bound for integral

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

How to calculate or bound from below  the following integral
$$
\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\left(1-\frac{x^2}{6}\right)^{2n}dx
$$

Comment: This is $\simeq$ the Taylor series expansion of $\dfrac{\sin x}x$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you see $$\left(1-\frac{x^2}{6}\right)^{2n}\geq\left(1-\frac{(\pi/2)^2}{6}\right)^{2n}\geq\left(1-\frac{2}{3}\right)^{2n}=\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^{2n}$$ so $$\int\limits_{0}^{\pi/2}\left(1-\frac{x^2}{6}\right)^{2n}dx\geq \left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^{2n}\int\limits_{0}^{\pi/2}dx=\frac{\pi}{2}.\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^{2n}=\frac{\pi}{2.9^n}$$

Comment: I do not understand the last step. Shouldn't the denominator be $2*9^n$?

Comment: you are right. I will correct.

Answer (score 0):

Staying with the same approach as guest, I should not simplify the second term and I should stay with $\left(1-\frac{\pi ^2}{24}\right)^{2 n}$ which, by the end will leads to $$\frac{1}{2} \pi  \left(1-\frac{\pi ^2}{24}\right)^{2 n}$$